# Questions on $R(K_l + \overline{K_t}, T_s) \le l(s-1)+t$

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Following C. C. Rousseau and J. Sheehan "A class of ramsey problems involving trees" Journal of London Math. Soc. $1978$,  I have some dudes about their proof for $R(K_l + \overline{K_t}, T_s) \le l(s-1)+t$.

Their proof uses induction on $s$. Suppose we use blue/red colorations of $K_p$ (with $p=l(s-1)+t$). Case $s=2$ holds if and only if any 2-coloration of $K_p$ have at least a red edge, but What if I color all edges of $K_p$ blue ?.

Suppose $(F_1,F_2)$ is a blue/red factorization of $K_p$ such that $K_l + \overline{K_t}$ is not a subgraph of $F_1$ neither $T_s$ is a subgraph of $F_2$, consider $T_{s-1} = T_s - v$ for some end vertex $v$ of $T_s$. By induction hypothesis $T_{s-1}$ is a subgraph of $F_2$, then exist a vertex $x$ in $V(T_{s-1})$ such that $xy \in E(F_1)$ for every $y \in V(K_p) - V(T_{s-1})$ (note $\vert V(K_p) - V(T_{s-1})\vert = (l-1)(s-1)+t$).

Then, if $l=1$ necessarily $x$ is adjacent to the $t$ vertices outside $T_{s-1}$ with edges in $F_1$, but What if these $t$ vertices have $F_1$ edges among them? I think this could be possible but then this not produces $K_{1,t}$ as a subgraph of $F_1$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is $T_s$? An arbitrary tree on $s$ vertices, or something more specific?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! $T_s$ is any tree of order $s$.

Comment: I'm looking at the paper. It seems that they only require that the blue edges *contain* a copy of $K_l+\bar K_t$, meaning that they do not add the requirement that the complement of $K_l+\bar K_t$ in the corresponding graph of $l+t$ vertices be red.

Comment: (At least, that seems to be the natural way to interpret line $3$ of the paper, and the only way to make sense of their arguments.)